Grails 5.3.3 | Log application.yml right before it is applied
I have a Grails 5.3.3 application and I have problem with application configurations. application.yml file, application-test.yml file, env vars. May I log the final configuration properties before they are applied.
It is important to log them before they applied, because once they are applied the application breaks.
May there be any changes to logback.groovy or custom logging classes?

Please, note that the properties must be logged BEFORE they are applied, thank you
